# EmberJS: Return to current route after login

Tags: ember.js

I have an app where anonymous users can see read-only views. When a user clicks a link to log in, I want to save the current route and model and restore it after successful authentication.

This is a little different from most examples that intercept a transition in beforeModel and redirect to log in.

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        logIn: function() {
            this.set('previousPath', this.get('currentPath'));
            this.transitionToRoute('login');
        }
    }
});

App.LoginController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: 'application',
    username: '',
    password: '',

    actions: {
        logIn: function () {
            var self = this;

            App.session.logIn(this.get('username'), this.get('password')).then(
                function() {
                    var route = self.get('controllers.application.previousPath')
                    self.transitionToRoute(route);
                });
        }
    }
});
```

This works fine for static routes, but for dynamic routes the model and route parameters are lost.

How do I capture either the current controller's model or route parameters so I can restore them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a way to do this that is similar to the intercept-redirect-retry pattern.

First, remember the most recent transition in the application route as long as it isn't the transition to login:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    beforeModel: function(transition) {
        this._saveTransition(transition);
    },
    actions: {
        willTransition: function (transition) {
            this._saveTransition(transition);
        }
    },
    _saveTransition: function (transition) {
        if (transition.targetName !== 'login') {
            this.controllerFor('login').set('previousTransition', transition);
        }
    }
});
```

`beforeModel` fires when the app is entered or if the page is hard refreshed. `willTransition` fires on every subsequent transition.

Then LoginController can retry the previous transition after successful authentication:

```
App.LoginController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    username: '',
    password: '',

    actions: {
        logIn: function () {
            var self = this;

            App.session.logIn(this.get('username'), this.get('password')).then(
                function() {
                    var previousTransition = self.get('previousTransition');

                    if (previousTransition) {
                        previousTransition.retry();
                        return;
                    }

                    self.transitionToRoute('index');
                });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The guides have a case which seems to be exactly what you are looking for.

```
App.SomeAuthenticatedRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  beforeModel: function(transition) {
    if (!this.controllerFor('auth').get('userIsLoggedIn')) {
      var loginController = this.controllerFor('login');
      loginController.set('previousTransition', transition);
      this.transitionTo('login');
    }
  }
});

App.LoginController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    login: function() {
      // Log the user in, then reattempt previous transition if it exists.
      var previousTransition = this.get('previousTransition');
      if (previousTransition) {
        this.set('previousTransition', null);
        previousTransition.retry();
      } else {
        // Default back to homepage
        this.transitionToRoute('index');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

for more details see [STORING AND RETRYING A TRANSITION](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/preventing-and-retrying-transitions/#toc_storing-and-retrying-a-transition)

Comment: This example prevents anonymous users from accessing the route. The question I asked is how to allow anonymous users to transition to the route, then if they decide to log in, they can return to that route after logging in. This is not exactly the same as what is in the guides.